# Installer crashed issue 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I have created a customize ISO of Ubuntu 16.04 through Remastersys, but when I install Ubuntu with this customized ISO after copying files it shows Installer crashed error.

The same process working fine with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: can you create the iso through any other resource? Say, etcher

Comment: Use linuxrespin, it is a fork of so called Remastersys. The site says Remastersys is abandoned